# how to pass a variable to system command in ruby?

Tags: ruby

In my ruby script I need to pass a file path to system command. For example, its like

system("run.exe -l C:\") where run.exe is my command and -l determines the local path.

Now if someone copies this to other machine drive C can be changed to drive E.

So my doubt is how to make it as a variable or how to take the current folder path in this.

Any suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: `system('run.exe', '-l', c_drive_or_whatever)`

Answer (score 3):

mu is too short and Jan give answers, but in general, you can put ruby commands in `#{...}` within `"..."`. In this case, you can do:

```
system("fixed_string_1#{ruby_command_1}fixed_string_2#{ruby_command_2}fixed_string_3...")
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to look at [ARGF](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/ARGF.html) and [ARGV](http://ruby.about.com/od/rubyfeatures/a/argv.htm)

Comment: I meant to make C:\ the local drive path variable. MEans for my scripts it will be C drive for someone else its D:\ . So how can i pass it as variable to take the folders current path.